# Unable to import even after installing the packages

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have installed numpy, scipy, scikit learn and other required packages. Still when I try to import them in python, it shows no module found.

```
pip install -U numpy scipy scikit-learn
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Collecting scipy
  Downloading scipy-0.17.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (39.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 39.5MB 32kB/s 
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in /home/tecsadmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Found existing installation: scipy 0.17.0
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (scipy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling scipy-0.17.0:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tecsadmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/tecsadmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/tecsadmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 736, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/home/tecsadmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 742, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/home/tecsadmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/home/tecsadmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
    os.unlink(src)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy-0.17.0.egg-info'
tecsadmin@BLITZ:~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 17 2016, 04:41:21) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
>>>
```

**Update**

```
admin@BLITZ:~$ sudo pip install -U numpy scipy scikit-learn
[sudo] password for tecsadmin: 
The directory '/home/tecsadmin/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/tecsadmin/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Collecting scipy
  Downloading scipy-0.17.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (39.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 39.5MB 32kB/s 
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Found existing installation: scipy 0.17.0
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (scipy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling scipy-0.17.0:
      Successfully uninstalled scipy-0.17.0
Successfully installed scipy-0.17.1
tecsadmin@BLITZ:~$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 17 2016, 04:41:21) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
tecsadmin@BLITZ:~$ pip freeze | grep numpy 
numpy==1.11.0
tecsadmin@BLITZ:~$ pip freeze | grep scipy
scipy==0.17.1
tecsadmin@BLITZ:~$ pip freeze | grep scikit-learn
scikit-learn==0.17.1
tecsadmin@BLITZ:~$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 17 2016, 04:41:21) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named scipy
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Comment: You didn't install the libraries, you got an error.

Comment: @user123 reinstall them using sudo pip install -U numpy scipy scikit-learn

Comment: @wind85 please chekc the update

Comment: Can you run a pip freeze?

Comment: @shivsn I didnt get you. It says requirement already satisfied. To :lapinkoira what is taht?

Comment: when you run pip freeze it show all the python packages installed, can you run it and double check it has been already installed? it should display a list of packages

Comment: please check new udpate in the question

Comment: You are probably using another python which hasnt the installed packages or the user which runs python cant access them, check which python are you using with 'which python' and check if it has the libraries

Comment: did you try this `sudo apt-get install python-scipy`.

Comment: share the output of `which python` and `which pip`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if related but you are having a `permission denied` error, try with 
`sudo pip install -U numpy scipy scikit-learn`

To double check your installation run `pip freeze`

```
$ pip freeze | grep numpy 
$ numpy==1.9.2
```

That way you really check if it has been succesfuly installed

Also I would suggest you to use python virtual environments https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/ so you dont have to play with sudo permissions

Comment: Run pip freeze, it should show numpy and scipy as installed, let's check it

Comment: Ok can you run a 'which python'

Answer (score 1):

You haven't installed the libs you got error 13 permission denied. Reinstall them using the command:

```
sudo pip install numpy scipy scikit-learn
```

Comment: I installed it using Sudo, still showing same error

Comment: @user123 you have multiple site-packages on your machine. Either you set up a virtual env (highly suggested) and install all the packages you need over there or reinstall the current packages with pip install --force-reinstall packages name.